# Abnormal increase in loss after 75 epochs (Using MSE and Binary Crossentropy)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, mse

I have trained a tensorflow.keras model over the night and was suprised about the training process (please see the attached picture). Can anyone tell me, what can produce such an effect during training? I have trained with mse (right) and one other loss displayed (binary crossentropy).
I have trained an autoencoder with 'normal' samples. The validation samples are 'anomaly' samples.

If you need more information, please let me know.

[image]

**Edit:** I might found the reason, but I am not sure: I have features as input-data, which do not have values strictly in [0,1], actually I have nearly all  values in [0,1] but a few values a little bit bigger than 1. As I am training with the MSE, I thought this should not be a problem, but as reference I also use the binary crossentropy loss (needs values in [0,1]). This might cause some iritation to the training. I am using:

```
loss = tensorflow.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(name='MeanSquaredError')
autoencoder.compile(optimizer=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate), loss=loss, metrics=[tensorflow.keras.metrics.BinaryCrossentropy()])
```

and livelossplot:

```
callbacks=[PlotLossesKeras(outputs=[MatplotlibPlot(figpath=save_string_plot)]),TensorBoard(log_dir="autoencoder\\" + string_name_model)],
```

At the moment I am retraining the model with feature values strictly in [0,1].

--> The retraining got to epoch 175 and then crashed, so i think this was not the solution (adapt feature strictly into [0,1]). Let us try the second possible solution (gradient clipping). Stay tuned. :)

[image]

**Edit:** One other solution might be gradient clipping, see:

https://neptune.ai/blog/understanding-gradient-clipping-and-how-it-can-fix-exploding-gradients-problem

--> Also this training did not work out. Loss explodes also at 175 epochs.

**New pictures** with the two possible solutions, which did not work out (but both exploded nearly at the same position):

[image]

**Edit:** I also tried batch normalization to avoid the loss explosion, but also this try did not work out.

Comment: Both possible solutions did not work out, in both cases (features strictly in [0,1] and gradient clipping with clipnorm = 1) I got nearly the same training plots (around epoch 175 the loss explodes, see figure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

-I reinstalled python completely and changed the learning rate to a smaller value (I think the learning rate was the main factor) and since then, no loss explosition occured anymore (trained now several times).